# For Assembly.Location, what determines if value is local or UNC path?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get the physical path of an assembly and am using Assembly.Location [[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx). My question is what determines whether a local or UNC path is returned? I only want the local path.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN on CodeBase which is here: [MSDN on Assembly.CodeBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase.aspx)

> The CodeBase is a URL to the place where the file was found, while the
>   Location is the path from where it was actually loaded. For example,
>   if the assembly was downloaded from the internet, its CodeBase may
>   start with "http://", but its Location may start with "C:\". If the
>   file was shadow copied, the Location would be the path to the copy of
>   the file in the shadow-copy dir.
>
> It’s also good to know that the CodeBase is not guaranteed to be set
>   for assemblies in the GAC. Location will always be set for assemblies
>   loaded from disk, however.

As you can see from this little example, UNC is not used for local assemblies,
even for those in the GAC:

```
public void WriteAssemblyLocations()
{
    Assembly[] assList = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    foreach (Assembly assembly in assList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(assembly.Location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting but my question is about what situations would cause the Assembly.Location to return a local path vs a UNC path.